# 2012 nissan sentra

Tags: nissan, misfire, sentra

**Help**I was driving down the highway and out of nowhere my car starting shaking real bad and acted as if it was struggling to move when i hit 60 and then struggled the whole time after that to get it home. I could only drive about 15mph, the faster i tried to go the worse the problem. It barely got up a hill. I haven't driven it again but when i start it up...it definitely struggles a tad and my exhaust is continuously making a putting sound but no smoke.  Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This sounds like a cylinder misfire, however there's not enough information to say for sure. Your car has a computer which manages the engine and if it senses something wrong it will give you On-Board Diagnostics (OBD) codes which can be read by a special reader, you could get an inexpensive one or most auto parts stores will do it for free. In the meantime check your spark plug cables and plugs.